Positive part of conditional expectation is conditional expectation of the positive part, $E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^+=E[Y^+|\mathcal{G}]$
Assume that $Y$ is in $L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$, let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-sigma algebra of $\mathcal{A}$. How do we then prove that
$$E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^+=E[Y^+|\mathcal{G}]?$$
Attempt:
I define the sets
$G_n=\{\omega \in \Omega: E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^+>E[Y^+|\mathcal{G}]>\frac{1}{n}\}$.
If I can show that  $P(G_n)=0$ we are done(EDIT: Or maybe not?, because then I must also take into the case where $E[Y^+|\mathcal{G}]=0?$). Note that $G_n \in \mathcal{G}$. Note that $E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^-(\omega)\cdot 1_{G_n}(\omega)$ must be zero a.s..
I want to show that $E[ (E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^+-E[Y^+|\mathcal{G}])\cdot 1_{G_n}]=0$, then I will be done. I get:
$$E[E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^+1_{G_n}]=E[E[Y|\mathcal{G}]1_{G_n}]=E[Y1_{G_n}],$$ since $E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^-(\omega)\cdot 1_{G_n}(\omega)=0$ a.s.
If I can show that $E[Y^+|\mathcal{G}]=E[Y1_{G_n}],$ I will be done. The problem is that I do not know how to show that $Y^-(\omega)\cdot 1_{G_n}(\omega)=0$ a.s.
Do you see how to complete it?

False.  Even when $\mathcal G$ is trivial ${\varnothing, \Omega}$: in that case  it would mean $\mathbb{E}[Y]^+ = \mathbb{E}[Y^+]$.  When given a problem about conditional expectations, first check the two extreme cases: the trivial $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{G} = \mathcal A$.  Note: Jensen's inequality does tell us $E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^+ \le E[Y^+|\mathcal{G}]$.

@GEdgar Thank you very much.

Actually, for a reasonable question which has been sorted out in comments, rather than close the question, a better use of the site is to convert the answer-in-the-comments to an actual answer.

The statement of the questioner is not true in general. As pointed out in the comments, the function $\phi(x)=\max(x,0)=x_+$ is convex. By the conditional Jensen's inequality, if $X\in L_1(P)$, then
$$\begin{equation}
(E[X|\mathcal{G}])_+= \phi(E[X|\mathcal{G}])\leq E[\phi(X)|\mathcal{G}]=E[X_+|\mathcal{G}]
\end{equation}
$$
Consider the standard Lebesgue space $([0,1],\mathcal{B},m)$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and $m$ is Lebesgue's measure. Define $X(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$ and $\mathcal{G}=\{\emptyset,[0,1]\}$. Then
$$ (E[X|\mathcal{G}])_+=0<E[X_+|\mathcal{G}]=\int^1_0 (\sin(2\pi x))_+\,dx$$
